# remove a selected row from jtable on button click

Tags: java, swing, jtable, actionevent

I want to remove a Selected row from a table in java.
The event should be performed on button click.
I will be thank full if someone helps...

For example there is a table named sub_table with 3 columns i.e sub_id, sub_name,class.
when I select one of the rows from that table and click delete button that particular row should be deleted..

Comment: Soooooo..... no code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117888/how-to-remove-a-row-from-jtable) one.

Comment: no...i am completely stucked plz help

Comment: Stuck on where? Any code.

Comment: ok....thanx I got it....

Answer (score 10):

It's very simple.

- Add  `ActionListener` on button.
- Remove selected row from the model attached to table.

Sample code: (table having 2 columns)

```
Object[][] data = { { "1", "Book1" }, { "2", "Book2" }, { "3", "Book3" }, 
                    { "4", "Book4" } };

String[] columnNames = { "ID", "Name" };
final DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);

final JTable table = new JTable(model);
table.setSelectionMode(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);


JButton button = new JButton("delete");
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // check for selected row first
        if (table.getSelectedRow() != -1) {
            // remove selected row from the model
            model.removeRow(table.getSelectedRow());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: It's worth nothing that the "view" index given by `table.getSelectedRow()` is not always the same as the "model" index. For example, if the table is sorted, all of the indices may be different. You can convert the index from `getSelectedRow()` into the model index with [`table.convertRowIndexToModel(int index)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertRowIndexToModel-int-).

Comment: @cubrr yes you are right. Thanks for correcting it.