# How to delete a row from jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton, tablecelleditor

I want to change the action of the button to delete. I have this code:

```
package buttonexample;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;


public class ButtonExample {

public JTable table;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    final ButtonExample example = new ButtonExample();
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            example.createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}

private void createAndShowGUI() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Button Example");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    table = new JTable(new JTableModel()); 
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true); 

    TableCellRenderer buttonRenderer = new JTableButtonRenderer();
    //table.getColumn("Button1").setCellRenderer(buttonRenderer);
    table.getColumn("Button2").setCellRenderer(buttonRenderer);
    table.addMouseListener(new JTableButtonMouseListener(table));

    frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 200));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static class JTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final String[] COLUMN_NAMES = new String[] {"Id", "Stuff", "Asdfsdf", "Button2"};
    private static final Class<?>[] COLUMN_TYPES = new Class<?>[] {Integer.class, String.class, String.class,  JButton.class};

    @Override public int getColumnCount() {
        return COLUMN_NAMES.length;
    }

    @Override public int getRowCount() {
        return 4;
    }

    @Override public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
        return COLUMN_NAMES[columnIndex];
    }

    @Override public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        return COLUMN_TYPES[columnIndex];
    }

    @Override public Object getValueAt(final int rowIndex, final int columnIndex) {

        switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0: return rowIndex;
            case 1: return "Text for "+rowIndex;
            case 2: return "Column for "+rowIndex;
            case 3: final JButton button = new JButton(COLUMN_NAMES[columnIndex]);
                    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                                                            // When this is clicked the whole row will be deleted.
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(JOptionPane.getFrameForComponent(button), 
                                    "Button clicked for row "+rowIndex);
                        }
                    });
                    return button;
            default: return "Error";
        }
    }   
}

private static class JTableButtonRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {        
    @Override public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object     value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        JButton button = (JButton)value;
        if (isSelected) {
            button.setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
            button.setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
        } else {
            button.setForeground(table.getForeground());
            button.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Button.background"));
        }
        return button;  
    }
}

private static class JTableButtonMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {
    private final JTable table;

    public JTableButtonMouseListener(JTable table) {
        this.table = table;
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        int column = table.getColumnModel().getColumnIndexAtX(e.getX());
        int row    = e.getY()/table.getRowHeight(); 

        if (row < table.getRowCount() && row >= 0 && column < table.getColumnCount() &&                    
column >= 0) {
            Object value = table.getValueAt(row, column);
            if (value instanceof JButton) {
                ((JButton)value).doClick();
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

But the `(DefaultTableModel)someTable.getModel(); model.removeRow(row);` I can't make it work because the table model does not have any name and I don't know what to name it. I have tried initializing a table model and I get error saying non-static variable model cannot be reference to a static context. Is there a way to delete the row in a static context?

Comment: Do not put ANY ui logic into a model, of any kind, it does not belong there.  Do not return any type of `Component` from a model, the responsibility for rendering the data from a model is the role of the view and in this case a `TableCellRenderer`

Comment: @MadProgrammer please whos Camrik :-)

Comment: refer this link, they have described here nicely


[how to delete row][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117888/how-to-remove-a-row-from-jtable

Comment: @mKorbel I had to do it off the top my head :P

Comment: refer this link, they have described here nicely


[how to delete row][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117888/how-to-remove-a-row-from-jtable

Comment: camickr has an [excellent tutorial](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/) which may help you

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes I have read camickr's tutorial and I just found that code somewhere. It is working. The model doesn't have any name to refer to so that I can delete it. Also about the component that you said what should I do with it?

Comment: @swapnilgandhi I've seen it and none of it works in my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [example by](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/) camickr is probably a more reusable solution, but for the sake of education...

- Rendering of cells is the domain of the view
- Model's should never contain components, especially if you're thinking about rendering them to the screen, this is simply the wrong approach to take...
- You need to set up a `TableCellEditor` which will act as the means by which you can retrieve notification of the edit actions (mouse click or keypress)

This is a basic example, for simplicity, I've used a `DefaultTableModel` as it has a nice `removeRow` method, but conceivably, you could use any `TableModel`, so long as you provided the means to remove a row and modified by the editor to support it...

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.EventObject;
import javax.swing.AbstractCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.event.CellEditorListener;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

public class ButtonExample {

    public JTable table;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final ButtonExample example = new ButtonExample();
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                example.createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Button Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        table = new JTable(new ExampleTableModel());
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

        table.getColumn("action").setCellRenderer(new ButtonCellRenderer());
        table.getColumn("action").setCellEditor(new ButtonCellEditor());

        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static class ExampleTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {

        public ExampleTableModel() {
            super(new Object[]{"id", "stuff", "blah", "action"}, 0);
            for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
                addRow(new Object[]{index, "Text for " + index, "Na na", index});
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return columnIndex == 3;
        }

    }

    public static class ButtonCellRenderer extends JButton implements TableCellRenderer {

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            if (value != null) {
                setText("Delete row " + value.toString());
            } else {
                setText("Delete Me");
            }
            if (isSelected) {
                setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
                setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
            } else {
                setForeground(table.getForeground());
                setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Button.background"));
            }
            return this;
        }
    }

    public static class ButtonCellEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor {

        private JButton editor;
        private Object value;
        private int row;
        private JTable table;

        public ButtonCellEditor() {
            editor = new JButton();
            editor.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (table != null) {
                        fireEditingStopped();
                        TableModel model = table.getModel();
                        if (model instanceof DefaultTableModel) {
                            ((DefaultTableModel) model).removeRow(row);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getCellEditorValue() {
            return value;
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
            this.table = table;
            this.row = row;
            this.value = value;
            if (value != null) {
                editor.setText("Delete row " + value.toString());
            } else {
                editor.setText("Delete Me");
            }
            if (isSelected) {
                editor.setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
                editor.setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
            } else {
                editor.setForeground(table.getForeground());
                editor.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Button.background"));
            }
            return editor;
        }
    }

}
```

Take a closer look at [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details

This is just a personal preference, but I prefer to use a toolbar or menu item and key bindings to provide this support.  Buttons in a table just seem so...dated - IMHO

Comment: Hi @MadProgrammer. Your code does work but when changing the `for loop` it doesn't add anything. Why is that? I've put the number in a variable like `.size();`

Comment: That depends, how did you change the `for-loop`?  What is the value of `size()`?

Comment: `for (int index = 0; index < items.size(); index++)` and the value is 3. I think I need to refresh the whole table so that it would get updated.

Comment: The code above works but there's no delete function in the button. What is the difference between your code and the one that I've posted above? Shouldn't be like the same but different way of writing the code?

Comment: First of all. I changed the cell renderer, I changed the data that was been managed by the model (for the "button column"), I added a cell editor to handle the functionality of actually deleting the row...

Comment: Is there no way to just add delete function is my code above? I really appreciate your answer but it doesn't work in my code. I think it doesn't update the data in the table because I get 0 in `items.size();`. That's why it doesn't print.

Comment: Okay. If it won't work then how can I re-run the whole program again? or refresh the whole table?

Comment: You have two examples which demonstrate how to solve your problem, in way that would be suitable to your users, but you can't seem to find away to utilise them?  If you want to refresh the table model, then create a new instance

Comment: Thank you for solving my problem but I have found a way to create delete function in my code. Thanks for everything!