# JTable with JButton inside cell

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I want to make a booking rooms application with a schedule.
I create a table `classes` in the database:

`idseance, idsalle, IdProf, idmodule, day, 8H (type boolean), 10H (type boolean), 14h, 16H`.

My code displays the table like this :

[image: http://s15.postimg.org/5m4l78hvf/Capture.png]

```
public class Fenetre extends JFrame {
    private Statement st = null;
    private ResultSet rs;

    private JTable tableau;
    connection con=new connection();

    public Fenetre() throws SQLException{
        st=con.getStatement();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setTitle("Emploi de Temps");
        this.setSize(700, 500);

        Object[][] data= new Object[5][4] ;
        String Sql="Select * from seance";
        rs=st.executeQuery(Sql);

        while(rs.next()) {
            switch (rs.getString("jour")){
                case "lundi":
                if (rs.getBoolean("8")){
                    data[0][0] = rs.getInt("Idmodule");
                }else{
                    data[0][0] = new JButton("Ajouter");
                }
                if (rs.getBoolean("10")){
                    data[0][1] = rs.getInt("Idmodule");
                }else {
                    data[0][1] = new JButton("Ajouter");
                }
                if(rs.getBoolean("14")){
                    data[0][2] = rs.getInt("Idmodule");
                }else {
                    data[0][2] =new JButton("Ajouter");
                }
                if(rs.getBoolean("16")){
                    data[0][3] = rs.getInt("Idmodule");
                }else {
                    data[0][3] =new JButton("Ajouter") ;
                }

                break;
                case "mardi" :
                if (rs.getBoolean("8")){
                    data[1][0] = rs.getInt("Idmodule");
                }else {
                    data[1][0] = new JButton("Ajouter");
                }
                if(rs.getBoolean("10")){
                    data[1][1] = rs.getInt("Idmodule");
                }else {
                    data[1][1] = new JButton("Ajouter");
                }
                if(rs.getBoolean("14")){
                    data[1][2] = rs.getInt("Idmodule");
                }else {
                    data[1][2] = new JButton("Ajouter");
                }
                if(rs.getBoolean("16")){
                    data[1][3] = rs.getInt("Idmodule");
                }  else {
                    data[1][3] = new JButton("Ajouter");
                }
            }
        }

        String[] title = {"8h_10h","10h_12h"," 14h_16h","16h_18h"};
        ZModel model = new ZModel(data, title);
        this.tableau = new JTable(model);
        changeSize(80, 80);
        this.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(tableau), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.tableau.setDefaultRenderer(JButton.class, new TableComponent());
    }

    public void changeSize(int width, int height){

        TableColumn col;
        for(int i = 0; i < tableau.getColumnCount(); i++){
            //On récupère le modèle de la colonne
            col = tableau.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
            //On lui affecte la nouvelle valeur
            col.setPreferredWidth(width);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < tableau.getRowCount(); i++){
            //On affecte la taille de la ligne à l'indice spécifié !
            tableau.setRowHeight(i, height);
        }
    }

    class ZModel extends AbstractTableModel{
        private Object[][] data;
        private String[] title;
        //Constructeur
        public ZModel(Object[][] data, String[] title){
            this.data = data;
            this.title = title;
        }

        //Retourne le nombre de colonnes
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return this.title.length;
        }

        //Retourne le nombre de lignes
        public int getRowCount() {
            return this.data.length;
        }

        //Retourne la valeur à l'emplacement spécifié
        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
            return this.data[row][col];
        }
        public String getColumnName(int col) {
            return this.title[col];
        } public Class getColumnClass(int col){
            //On retourne le type de la cellule à la colonne demandée
            //On se moque de la ligne puisque les types de données sont les mêmes quelle que soit la ligne
            //On choisit donc la première ligne
            return this.data[0][col].getClass();
        }
        //Retourne vrai si la cellule est éditable : celle-ci sera donc éditable
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col){
            if(getValueAt(0, col) instanceof JButton)
            return false;
            return true;

        }
    }
}
```

And the classes `TableComponent` :

```
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

public class TableComponent extends DefaultTableCellRenderer implements TableCellRenderer{

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        //Si la valeur de la cellule est un JButton, on transtype cette valeur
        setText((value != null) ? value.toString() : "Ajouter");
        if (value instanceof JButton)
        return (JButton) value;
        else
        return this;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the button is not active and the table cell at `[1][0]`  does not display the button.

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24625083/how-to-delete-a-row-from-jtable/24626105#24626105)

Comment: Don't store components within the model, ever.  Store state information within the model, which the renderer and editors will use to determine how to present and react to

Comment: What is the need to add buttons in the JTable? Do you want your cell to act like a permalink? If yes there are better ways available for this.

Comment: if i click to button to add (Ajouter en français) a new classe in hour and day spécific