# Dynamically Add/Remove Rows from JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have in my application two ComboBoxes for rows and columns for each JTable. Shown below:[image]

I want to add and remove rows and columns in each table dynamically. I know I would do something like `table.add()` but what about remove? For example if user selects 3 from Row combobox, it should add another row to it but what if user selects 2 back? It should remove that row inserted. So how do I do that?

I know it can be a stupid question but I am a newbie to Swing so people can't really expect much from me :(

Comment: Does this help you : `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117888/how-to-remove-a-row-from-jtable`

Comment: I know the `Remove()` method. But the thing is, how do I know if 2 is selected or 3? Like if JTable has 2 rows already, and user selects 3 from combo, it should `Add()` a row, and if user selects 2 again, it should `remove()` a row. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you want to control the dimension of the table using combo boxes. JTable renderers its underlying data model. Read more about tables in [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html). Adding and removing rows is actually manipulation of the data model. For example [DefaultTableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html) has many methods useful for your task: `addRow()`, `removeRow()`, `getRowCount()` etc.

It all depends on the data and task required. Check out this simple example that uses a custom table model that wraps Apache's [RealMatrix](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/linear/RealMatrix.html). You can choose whatever data structure you need. `DefaultTableModel` is also good an may be sufficient. The example has two combo boxes that adjust table size.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

import org.apache.commons.math3.linear.Array2DRowRealMatrix;
import org.apache.commons.math3.linear.RealMatrix;

public class TestTableDims extends JPanel{
    private MyTableModel model;
    private JTable table;
    private JComboBox rowsCombo;
    private JComboBox columnsCombo;

    public TestTableDims() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));

        model = new MyTableModel(2, 2);

        JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
        Integer[] test = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        rowsCombo = new JComboBox(test);
        rowsCombo.setSelectedItem(2);
        rowsCombo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                model.setRows(((Integer)rowsCombo.getSelectedItem()));
            }
        });

        buttonsPanel.add(new JLabel("rows"));
        buttonsPanel.add(rowsCombo);

        columnsCombo = new JComboBox(test);
        columnsCombo.setSelectedItem(2);
        columnsCombo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                model.setColumns(((Integer)columnsCombo.getSelectedItem()));
            }
        });

        buttonsPanel.add(new JLabel("columns"));
        buttonsPanel.add(columnsCombo);
        add(buttonsPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JTable table = new JTable();
        table.setModel(model);
        add(new JScrollPane(table));
    }

    class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
        private RealMatrix matrix;

        public MyTableModel(int rows, int columns) {
            matrix = new Array2DRowRealMatrix(rows, columns);
        }

        public void setRows(int rows) {
            matrix = new Array2DRowRealMatrix(rows, matrix.getColumnDimension());
            fireTableStructureChanged();
        }

        public void setColumns(int columns) {
            matrix = new Array2DRowRealMatrix(matrix.getRowDimension(), columns);
            fireTableStructureChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return matrix.getColumnDimension();
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return matrix.getRowDimension();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return Double.class;
        }

        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int column) {
            matrix.setEntry(row, column, (double)value);
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
            return matrix.getEntry(row, column);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(300, 200);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {   
            public void run() {   
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                TestTableDims panel = new TestTableDims();
                frame.add(panel);
                frame.pack();

                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```