# remove row from jtable

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable, matisse

i want to remove a row from  jtable in swing form
[image]

Jtable >> dragged autmatically from Netbeans swing ( Netbeans 8 )

```
private javax.persistence.EntityManager entityManager;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
private java.util.List<javaapplication1.Orders> ordersList;
private javax.persistence.Query ordersQuery;
private org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BindingGroup bindingGroup;
```

Jtable data >> bind auomatically from MySQL database

i want to delete the row from the jtable only not from the database

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    int selectedRow =  jTable1.getSelectedRow();
    if(selectedRow!=-1)
    {
        try {
            jTable1.remove(selectedRow);
            jTable1.revalidate();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: so, whats the problem with the above code?

Comment: Not WOrking , can not delete

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove a row from JTable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117888/how-to-remove-a-row-from-jtable)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At this line:

```
jTable1.remove(selectedRow);
```

This [remove(int index)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#remove-int-) method doesn't do what you think it does. It is inherited from [Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html) class and it is intended to remove components from a given container.

Instead of that you need to work with the [TableModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html) and remove the selected row from it. Since you are using [matisse](/questions/tagged/matisse) (NetBeans' GUI Builder) then the table model attached to your table will be an instance of [DefaultTableModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html), so you can do as follows:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    int viewIndex = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
    if(viewIndex != -1) {
        int modelIndex = jTable1.convertRowIndexToModel(viewIndex); // converts the row index in the view to the appropriate index in the model
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
        model.removeRow(modelIndex);
    }
}
```

Please take a look to:

- [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertRowIndexToModel-int-)
- [JTable#convertRowIndexToModel(int rowIndex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)
- [DefaultTableModel#removeRow(int rowIndex)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#removeRow-int-)

Comment: now that work after i add 
jtable1.setModel( new (DefaultTableModel) );

but when i try to loop on it he said : MOdel is empty

Answer (score 0):

Working with JTableBinding:

```
private JTableBinding<LpDetail, LpMaster, JTable> lpDetailListTableBinding;
```

you can perform this over the pojos directly:

```
protected void btnEliminarItemActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        int sustract = tb_DetLP.getSelectedRow();

        if (sustract >= 0) {
            selectedItem.setLpDetailList(org.jdesktop.observablecollections.ObservableCollections
                    .observableList(selectedItem.getLpDetailList()));
            selectedItem.getLpDetalleList().remove(sustract);                       
        }

    }
```