# How to delete row from bound JTable?

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable

I have a `JTable` bound to MySQL. I already have done code to insert data.

But i don't know how to delete.

I have this sample delete method that works in other simple projects.

```
public String deleteItem(String name) {

    String answer = "";
    try {
        Connection con = Connect.getConnection();
        String sql = "Delete FROM item where name = ?";
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1, name);

        ps.executeUpdate();

        ps.close();
        con.close();

        answer = "OK";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        answer = e.toString();
    }

    return answer;
}
```

Even when I worked with an unbound table I have done this [remove row from jtable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27425476/remove-row-from-jtable) that did well for me.

But now its a table bound to MySQL and I can't find a way to delete row... already searched on the internet. Found nothing.

PS: i'm using netbeans. i right-clicked jtable > bind > elements , to bind table.

Comment: Are you sure id is not `int` but `string` ?

Comment: oh yes, but its just a sample there. I edited to make sense

Comment: This is not your code ?

Comment: yes, this is my code, but i don't know how can i use it in this case.

Comment: How is the table "bound" to the database?

Comment: i want to delete a row in jtable without writing an id or name in a textfield, only from button.

Comment: MadProgrammer , in netbeans i right-clicked jtable > bind > elements > choose database and table

Comment: `i right-clicked jtable > bind > elements > choose database and table` - so then the IDE must generate some code to do the deletion, or maybe it is only bound for the query and you need to write the delete code yourself. If you need to write the code yourself then you need to override the `removeRow(...)` method of your TableModel to add the code to manually delete the row from the database.

Comment: Possible duplicate [remove row from jtable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27425476/remove-row-from-jtable)

Comment: The key is to understand (and share with us) how did Netbeans bind the `JTable` to the database.

Comment: Can you show your table code, that way we can be able to help.

Comment: thanks for help buddies, I found an way to do it, I posted a answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I found a way!

First, I changed my deleteItem method, to delete by id

#### ItemDAO.java

```
public String deleteItem(int ID_item) {
    
    String answer = "";
    try {
        Connection con = Connect.getConnection();
        String sql = "Delete FROM item where ID_Item = ?";
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setInt(1, ID_item);

        ps.executeUpdate();
        
        ps.close();
        con.close();

        answer = "OK";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        answer = e.toString();
    }

    return answer;
}
```

Then the action in delete button goes like this.

#### Form.java

```
private void btnDeleteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
     int column = 0;    // get the first column which is ID_Item
     int row = tableItem.getSelectedRow();  //get row selected by user
     int value = (int) tableItem.getModel().getValueAt(row, column); // store ID_Item value
     String answer = new ItemDAO().deleteItem(value);  // call up deleteItem method
             
     if(answer.equals("OK")) {
         System.out.println("OK"); // just for test
         itemList.clear();    // this is needed to update the bound table after Insert/Delete/Update etc
         itemList.addAll(itemQuery.getResultList()); // same as above comment
     }else{
         System.out.println("ERROR"); // just for test.
     }
```

Maybe isn't the most beautiful way to do it, but it works.