# How do I make Swing delete an entry from a table by selecting rows and clicking delete?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, abstracttablemodel

I have a panel with one table in it. The table is a simple view of entities from database. I want the user to be able to select the entries(=rows) and click delete.

I have my own table model that extends AbstractTableModel.

I didn't find any method in AbstractTableModel to do this. Does it mean that this is not supported?

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117888/how-to-remove-a-row-from-jtable

Comment: @Maxvader thanks, I just overrided the removeRow method. This doesn't solve my main problem -- I want the user to be able to select row(s) and click delete and have them deleted. (rightclick on the row is also okay)

Comment: Well this side of the problem  has nothing to do with the model.
You just have to add some kind of control in the view that calls the change in the model.
For example add a column with a delete button and programmatically add in the button command the row number and in the listener call the delete.

Comment: @Maxvader you are right

Answer (score 1):

Delete a row(s) from a table is not always straight forward as the table could be sorted or filtered which means you first need to convert the view row to the model row before you can delete the row from the table model:

Here is an example that shows how this can be done:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class ItemDeletion extends JPanel
{
    private JList<String> list;
    private JTable table;

    public ItemDeletion()
    {
        setLayout( new BorderLayout(5, 5) );

        String[] items =
        {
            "One",
            "Two",
            "Three",
            "Four",
            "Five",
            "Six",
            "Seven",
            "Eight",
            "Nine",
            "Ten"
        };

        //  Add the list

        DefaultListModel<String> listModel = new DefaultListModel<String>();

        for (String item: items)
            listModel.addElement( item );

        list = new JList<String>( listModel );


        JButton listDelete = new JButton( "Delete From List" );
        listDelete.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                DefaultListModel model = (DefaultListModel)list.getModel();
                int row = list.getSelectedIndex();

                while (row != -1)
                {
                    model.removeElementAt( row );
                    row = list.getSelectedIndex();
                }
            }
        });

        JPanel listPanel = new JPanel( new BorderLayout(5, 5) );
        listPanel.add(new JScrollPane( list ), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        listPanel.add(listDelete, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        //  Add the table

        DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(0, 1);
        List<String> tableItems = Arrays.asList( items );
        Collections.shuffle( tableItems );

        for (String item: tableItems)
        {
            System.out.println( item );
            tableModel.addRow( new String[]{item} );
        }

        table = new JTable( tableModel );

        table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
        ((DefaultRowSorter)table.getRowSorter()).toggleSortOrder(0);

        JButton tableDelete = new JButton( "Delete From Table" );
        tableDelete.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
                int row = table.getSelectedRow();

                while (row != -1)
                {
                    int modelRow = table.convertRowIndexToModel( row );
                    model.removeRow( modelRow );
                    row = table.getSelectedRow();
                }
            }
        });

        JPanel tablePanel = new JPanel( new BorderLayout(5, 5) );
        tablePanel.add(new JScrollPane( table ), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        tablePanel.add(tableDelete, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        add(listPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        add(tablePanel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Multiple Item Deletion");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new ItemDeletion(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```