# Get index row of String date greater than 30 days JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

My problem is that I have a `JTable` with 2 vector data for data & column names respectively,

```
Vector<String> rowOne = new Vector<>(); 
rowOne.addElement("Harry");
rowOne.addElement("100414");
rowOne.addElement("21");
rowOne.addElement("239438"); 
rowOne.addElement("08/21/2016");
rowOne.addElement("30000");

Vector<String> rowTwo = new Vector<>();
rowTwo.addElement("Gordon");
rowTwo.addElement("34353");
rowTwo.addElement("25");
rowTwo.addElement("2538"); 
rowTwo.addElement("07/ 16/2016");
rowTwo.addElement("20000");

Vector<Vector> rowData = new Vector<>();
rowData.addElement(rowOne);
rowData.addElement(rowTwo);

Vector<String> columnNames = new Vector<>();
columnNames.addElement("Name");
columnNames.addElement("Cc");
columnNames.addElement("Age");
columnNames.addElement("Phone");
columnNames.addElement("Date");
columnNames.addElement("Amount");

DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(rowData, columnNames);
table = new JTable(model);
```

As we can see is a normal `JTable` with 6 columns, in which the fourth one is a string representing a date.

I tried to add a button with a action listener like this, in order to iterate over all rows of the JTable at the column 4 in order to get all string date values to compare it with the current date to verify if they're older than 30 days.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {

else if(e.getActionCommand().equals("limPago"))
        {
            DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
            int num = model.getRowCount();

            for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
            {
             //Right here i don't know how to identity the columns with date greater
             //than 30 days and take the jtable index corresponding to that row.
            }
    }
```

I need to get the index row corresponding to the `Object` of `JTable` that have the column 4 date with 30 days older.

Comment: (1-), Start "accepting" answers in other questions (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39060135/error-deleting-last-row-jtable) BEFORE you start posting new questions. Once again you haven't posted a SSCCE. Also not the code you posted in your last question isn't even the code you are executing in your program so how do we know the code you posted here is the code you are executing. That is another reason why a SSCCE should be posted with every question.

Answer (score 2):

Add instances of [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) to your `TableModel`, and return the correct type in your implementation of `getColumnClass()`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4553842/230513). `Date`  implements [`Comparable<T>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4553842/230513), making the comparison easy. Starting from the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4553842/230513) and adding 32 daily rows, the following `Action` prints rows *greater than or equal to* `then`, which has been initalized to a date 30 days hence:

Console:

```
30 Wed Sep 21 19:34:35 EDT 2016
31 Thu Sep 22 19:34:35 EDT 2016
```

Code:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 32; i++) {…}
…
f.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Scan") {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Calendar then = Calendar.getInstance();
        then.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 30);
        for (int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++) {
            Date d = (Date) model.getValueAt(i, 1);
            if (d.compareTo(then.getTime()) > -1) {
                System.out.println(i + " " + d);
            }
        }
    }
}), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
```

Change the predicate to `d.compareTo(then.getTime()) < 1` to see the rows *before* `then`.

[image]